# 'jQuery' is not defined when importing simplemodal

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-6, simplemodal

This only happens in IE6. With the following code I get the error 'jQuery' is not defined on line 9 char 1. There is no error when I remove the simplemodal line. I tried setting type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="Javascript" src="scripts/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for fun, what happens if you change https to http? Any difference?

Comment: any reason to be doing that at all?

Comment: Getting rid of the s does nothing.

Comment: You have the undefined check in place, but have you actually tried using the jQuery object (with and without the simplemodal plugin script line). E.g. do a document ready and alert. Does this work?

Comment: The alert works in IE8. Not in IE6. In IE6 with he simple modal we get the same error. In IE6 without the simplemodal line I get "Object expected".

Comment: I apologize for my stupidity. I was running IE6 from within one of Microsoft's VMs. I hadn't set up the proxy on IE6, so no wonder it couldn't download jQuery from Google. I feel like a fool. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Do you really need the `charset` attribute for `<script>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<script language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. And its not the jQuery line causing the issue. Its the simplemodal one.

Comment: using jquery-latest might result in future problems, not entirelly recommended, imo.

Answer (score 1):

if you write type="application/javascript" IE doesnt read the code inside the tag. You have to use text/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Move the loading of SimpleModal to after your undefined check.